# Number observations by group according to date of observation

Tags: r

I have a simple data frame consisting of dated observations for a series of IDs.

```
df<- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3), Date = c(1981,1947,1981,1992,1999,2001,2000,2001,2017,2019))
```

```
   ID Date
1   1 1981
2   1 1947
3   1 1981
4   1 1992
5   2 1999
6   2 2001
7   2 2000
8   2 2001
9   3 2017
10  3 2019
```

I'd simply like to number the observations for each ID based on the date of the observation. Earliest observation = 1, then 2, etc.

```
   ID Date order
1   1 1981     2
2   1 1947     1
3   1 1981     2
4   1 1992     3
5   2 1999     1
6   2 2001     3
7   2 2000     2
8   2 2001     3
9   3 2017     1
10  3 2019     2
```

I'm sure a question like this has been asked and answered before but I haven't been able to find it. I'd be grateful for any help or direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(order = dense_rank(Date)) %>%
  ungroup()
## A tibble: 10 x 3
#      ID  Date order
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1     1  1981     2
# 2     1  1947     1
# 3     1  1981     2
# 4     1  1992     3
# 5     2  1999     1
# 6     2  2001     3
# 7     2  2000     2
# 8     2  2001     3
# 9     3  2017     1
#10     3  2019     2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, good answer, upvote. But please don't post data as images, it's not hard to post the actual output and it even saves you the trouble of having to create the graphics file.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
> df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(order=rank(Date, ties.method = "min")) %>% ungroup()
# A tibble: 10 x 3
      ID  Date order
   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1     1  1981     2
 2     1  1947     1
 3     1  1981     2
 4     1  1992     4
 5     2  1999     1
 6     2  2001     3
 7     2  2000     2
 8     2  2001     3
 9     3  2017     1
10     3  2019     2
```

Comment: Oh yes, should not be 4 but 3 - indeed then the answer by @zimia is "correcter" using the `dense_rank` function

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, order := frank(Date, ties.method = 'dense'), ID]
```